# Distributing applications where the configuration settings are encrypted using Entrerprise library

Tags: .net, winforms, deployment, encryption, app-config

I have a thought about this but could not come with a good solution.

I have a windows application. I use enterprise library (3.1) Data Access Application Block. Now I use the DataProtectionConfigurationProvider to encrypt the connection strings.
This application has to be deployed across multiple machines. I don't want the end users to open EntLibConfig.exe and configure the connection strings. How do I go about this?

Thanks,
Ramjee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider as this allows the exporting of your key container for installation on another machine. This is not supported in the DataProtectionConfigurationProvider .

See this link for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxw286t2%28VS.80%29.aspx